# Probability of a Collision in Selection of Permutations

Tags: probability, data-analysis

Suppose I have a set of characters, say $\{a-z,A-Z,0-9\}$ $(n=62)$. Then I select a random permutation each containing $10$, e.g. $k=10$, characters. What would be the probability of a collision — a previously selected permutation gets selected again?

Comment: How many selections you've done please? If you've sampled many times already, the probability of selecting an existing permutation will be high.

Comment: The total number of permutations from the given set of characters with each permutation containing 10 characters would be $\frac{62!}{(62-10)!}=390164706723052800$

Comment: Well there are $62^{10}$ possible permutations (not combinations--which will be less) which is about $10^{17}$ permutations.  So the probability of getting a duplicate each time is $\approx \frac{n}{10^{17}}$... _however_ there is a _larger_ probability (due to a binomial-like random variable) that you will get a duplicate in $n$ tries.

Answer (score 0):

The distinction discussed in the Comments is whether symbols can be repeated or not in the
string of 10. For example, is "AAbe2de313" permitted, or does it
have to be something like "13daCVse82"?

The first way there are $62^{10}$ possibilities,
and the second way there are $P(62,10) = 62!/(62-10)!\,.\,$  (In the usual terminology
'combinations' are not involved in either of these.)

In each case, the probability
of repeating exactly the same characters in exactly the same
order in any *one* try is the reciprocal of the number of possibilities.

Your statement is a little vague. If your question is not
answered here, please leave a comment.

Comment: Symbol repetition within a single permutation is allowed as in the first example. I'm simply trying to find out the probability of a collision i.e. duplicate permutations. You say my question is a little vague, suggestions for clarifications are welcomed.

Comment: If you are asking for the probability of a 'collision' on any one single occasion, then it's $1/62^{10}.$ Of course, chances get larger if you keep trying repeatedly. For example, if you're talking about passwords, sometimes people (or programs) do make repeated tries.